# detect JSON schema from JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, schema

I've been looking around for a way to detect schema of a JSON object that comes from a JSON string, in Java.
What I find is a lot of ways to convert a JSON string into a POJO, but all of the examples I've found require the Java Class to convert the JSON to to be known and defined ahead of time.

My JSON is data and I don't know the structure of it so I can't do that.

I also see a lot of ways to serialize a POJO to JSON, and the answer to most of these questions is to use the Jackson module, but I still haven't found the answer to my question:

I want to read an JSON string which I don't know the structure of, and detect its schema. is there a module to do this? I could recurse through it and handle different cases, but this must have been done before!

I know I can read the JSON with something like

> mapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
>
> JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(in);

and I can supposedly read the schema of a Java Class with

> JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(myObjectClass.class);

but if i just do

> JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(json.getClass());

all I get out of this, no matter what the JSON string input is, is this:

> { "type":"Object" }

So, does anyone know how I can detect the schema of my unknown object?

I assume that has to do with building the POJO from the JsonNode properly, but I'm not sure how to get that.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: What do you need to do with it?

Comment: I need to detect a schema on incoming event, and check that future events matches the same schema. i.e. I want to check for consistency in the incoming JSON strings, especially type consistency.